# How to export war with different file version to different deployment destination

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, export, war

I am use myeclipse to develop tomcat web application.
When I finish developing and decide to export war file to upload to remote server, I always have to change the configuration file like hiberante.cfg.xml, to connect to different mysql server.

Is there any way, like maven plugin or something that could keep two copy a resource like the hiberante configuration file. So when i export war I could choose like by profile or anything like that to include different version of a/some resources?

Appriciated.

Comment: Export war will only look for configuration according to your Application Structure Configuration. You need to change config properties whenever export New build war if needed(different environment). You cannot have two configuration files. So You need to provide the particular specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's usually the job of your config manager (Chef, Ansible, etc.) or at least the job of your source management tool (Git, SVN, etc.) to choose/contain the right config.

My quick way of deploying using Git is to have a git production branch that contains one extra commit (that is config changes); and for deploy I would just rebase the production branch from the working branch and deploy.

Comment: yes, i will go with the branch and export alternative.